# How can I stream a map of polylines efficiently?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, streaming, query-optimization, geospatial

In our database we have a collection of `segment`s. Each `segment` has an ID and a `LineString` GeoJSON to describe the points of line. Each `segment` also has a set of properties like `totalElevationGain`, `distance`, `popularity` etc.

The goal of the app is to show these segments on a map (we are using Google maps) with colors etc.

The problem is that the querying seems to be inefficient. The problem is not with the database itself (we are using MongoDB 2dsphere indices and they work pretty well). The problem I think is how I am querying the backend.

When the map is loaded, I get the view bounds and send a request to give me the segments who are appear there (with a `$geoIntersect` and a rectangular `Polygon`). This works fine. The problem is that when the user moves even slightly away from the loaded bounds, I detect that the new bounds are not completely bounded by the loaded bounds and I send a query again with the new bounds.

```
Loaded bounds                               New bounds
       +                                          +
       |                                          |
       |                                          |
       |                                          |
       |                                          |
       |                                          |
       |                                          |
       v                                          v

      +---+-------------------------------------+---+
      |   |                                     |   |
      |   |                                     |   |
      |   |                                     |   |
      |   |                                     |   |
      |   |                                     |   |
      |   |                                     |   |
      |   |                                     |   |
      +---+-------------------------------------+---+
```

This could be optimized by removing the ids of the segments in the hidden area and send a request to the server with the extra added bounds to the right.

The problem gets more complicated when the new added bounds are not rectangular like:

```
         Loaded bounds
              +
              |
              |
              v
+-------------+-------------------+
|                                 |  New bounds
|                                 |       +
|                                 |       |
|                                 |       |
|                                 |       v
|                 +-----------------------+----------+
|                 |               |                  |
|                 |               |                  |
|                 |               |                  |
|                 |               |                  |
|                 |               |                  |
|                 |               |                  |
+---------------------------------+                  |
                  |                                  |
                  |                                  |
                  |                                  |
                  |                                  |
                  +----------------------------------+
```

Of course one could always subdivide the non-rectangular areas into multiple smaller rectangular areas but it feels like it is hacky.

### What I am asking

How is streaming of the map usually done?

I really want the user experience to be smooth and fast. I want to get rid of unnecessary requests. Also it gets more complicated as I would like to filter the segments shown in the map based on their properties.

Comment: Add a map server between your data and the client, like GeoServer, MapServer, QGIS Server, etc. Use the WMS service. And if you add a tile cache (GeoWebCache, MapProxy, etc, the user experience will be smooth and fast.

Comment: @jgrocha Thanks for your comment. Can you help me understand how they work? Do they need to interface with my backend (nodejs) or directly with the database (mongodb)? How does the usual process go? Do you know resources online I can check out? Also do you think it will take a long time to migrate from my current solution to one that uses the above mentioned technologies?